# How to enable the highest warning level in GCC compiler(Boost is heavily used)

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, compiler-construction, warnings

I just read a book which recommends enable the highest warning level in GCC. I just check the doc online, and found there are too much parameters. I want to enable the highest warning level, which parameter should I use?

And we use Boost heavily in our project.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` is a good start, if not everything you need.

Comment: just for anyone using clang on apple it's got `-Weverything`

Comment: @chris However, with new GCC versions (4.8.1 for me), you can never use Boost with that combination of flags, unless you specifically suppress the warnings generated by Boost code. `-Wunused-local-typedefs` anyone?

Comment: @MarkGarcia, Good point. It depends on which part of Boost (Regex gives no warnings), but I have seen them come up.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: Might be, but I prefer enabling many warning at once, and disabling some specific ones (with a reference to the issue), rather than not enabling them. I guess it's a white-listing vs black-listing approach.

Comment: @MarkGarcia You should be using -isystem to include third-party library headers, unless you plan on modifying the headers. This suppresses warnings from those headers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Contrary to cl which has 4 levels, gcc only has a [set of options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) that you can turn on or off.

As mentioned by others, the `-Wall` is the default, which turns on many warnings already. The `-pedantic` option adds a few more. And `-Wextra` yet another group...

But to really capture many warnings, you'll have to add many *manually*.

There is a set I like to use, although someone told me that some of those were contradictory, I find that list rather good for my development work:

`-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wundef -Wno-unused -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-parentheses -fdiagnostics-show-option`

Note that I make use of `-Werror` because otherwise you get warnings and tend to ignore them. With `-Werror`, no more ignoring anything! Write pristine code and your software is much more likely to work as expected.

Comment: With boost you may have to remove a few of the options to not have to turn them off in the code. One thing that a company I'm working with does is to create a set of wrappers for files that create problems. In them you can then use a #pragma to turn off the warnings that would otherwise be generated. For example: `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wold-style-cast"` would help if you use a macro that uses a C-like cast.

Comment: `-Wconversion` is another one you might consider

Answer (score -4):

I guess you can use the `-Wall`switch

Comment: This does not even remotely enable all warnings.